# Finding the domain of this trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I find the domain of this function?

$$f(x)=\frac{x\sin(x)+\cos(x)}{1-\cos(x)} + \frac{|x|-2}{x^2-4}$$

I assume we don't want the denominator to be zero, but do we have to combine the denominators first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since combining the denominators is just the product of both denominators, we know that  if either one is equal to zero, the function will be undefined there:

The function is undefined when:

- $1-\cos x = 0 \implies \cos x = 1 \implies x = 0 \pm 2\pi k, \;\;k\in \mathbb Z$;
- $x^2 - 4= 0 \implies x=2 \text{ or } x=-2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

No, just find the values for which $1-\cos(x)=0$ and $x^2-4=0$. Those values of $x$ restrict the domain.